# Laravel image not displaying when using form

Tags: laravel, image, file

Im trying to get image input from use using a form. I followed some youtube tutorial and follow the method to store the image path into my storage/app/images directory. However, when i try to display the images in my views it is not showing. Can anyone point me in the right direction? thankyou in advance

My form

```
 <form action="{{ url('publish-news') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter title" >
            </div>


            <textarea id="content" name="content"> </textarea>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input name="image" class="form-control file-form pr-2" type="file" id="formFile">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Publish</button>

            <script>
                var desc = CKEDITOR.instances.DSC.getData();
            </script>

        </form>
```

My controller

```
 public function addnews(Request $request)
    {
        $request -> validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required'

        ]);

        $content = $request->input('content');
        $title = $request ->input('title');
        $image = $request -> file('image');


            if ($image)
            {
                $newfile = $request->file('image');
                $file_path = $newfile->store('images');
                $timestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
                $data=array('title'=>$title,"content"=>$content,"image"=>$file_path,"timestamp"=>$timestamp);
                $query = DB::table('announcement')->insert($data);

                return view('admin.admin-announcement');


            }

    }
```

My view (i want to display the images here)

```
 <div class="container row m-lg-3">
            @foreach($announcements as $announcement)
                <div class="card col-lg" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('storage/'.$announcement->image)}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"> {{$announcement->title}}</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

My directory
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/NznNp.png][1]][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your files wherever you want within your Laravel application. Laravel's filesystem configuration file is located at `config/filesystems.php` . Within this file, you may configure all of your filesystem "disks".

Files are saved under the folder path named `storage` by default. You should create a symlink to your storage folder so that you can access it easier. The symlink makes files stored in the storage directory accessible from the web.

Execute this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

see also: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk